# Youtube API - Send MCN Network Join Invitation?

Tags: join, youtube-api, content-management-system

There is access to the CMS Youtube, rights management, with CMS can be sent invitations.

How to do it through the API?

This method should be used if https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channelSections/insert?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not possible to send channel invitation through the YouTube API. 
You have to manually send out invitations through the [YouTube content owner Dashboard](https://www.youtube.com/my_channels?o).